# Distribution of $X$ given $X+Y$ when $X$ and $Y$ follows indep negative binomial.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ follows negative binomial$(r,p)$, $Y$ follows negative binomial$(s,p)$. What is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X+Y$?

I have a feeling that this should follow some hypergeometric distribution, but I think I am messing some calculations.

I have done the calculations.

It turns out that:

$P(X=k|X+Y=v)= \frac{r+s-1}{v+r+s-1}$$v\choose{k}$ ${r+s-2}\choose{r-1}$$/$$v+r+s-2\choose k+r-1$.

I think I have made some mistakes in my calculation.
 As the distribution I got looks very much like hypergeometric except the first scaling factor.

Can some one verify if it the conditional distribution is indeed hypergeometric or not.

Comment: If $X \sim Nb(r,p)$ and $Y \sim Nb(s,p)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $X+Y \sim Nb(r+s,p)$.

Comment: Yes I know that. The problem is about the conditional distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to write $$\Pr[X = x \mid X+Y = n] = \frac{\Pr[X = x \cap X+Y = n]}{\Pr[X+Y = n]} = \frac{\Pr[X = x \cap Y = n-x]}{\Pr[X+Y = n]} \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \frac{\Pr[X = x]\Pr[Y = n-x]}{\Pr[X+Y = n]},$$ assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent negative binomial variables.  Then recall that the sum of two negative binomial random variables with the same Bernoulli trial parameter $p$, but with (not necessarily equal) count parameters $r_1$ and $r_2$, is negative binomial with trial parameter $p$ and count parameter $r_1 + r_2$.  This gives the distribution of the denominator; consequently, the rest is simply algebraic substitution.

Comment: Is the conditional distribution hypergeometric?

Comment: @SubhasishBasak - what makes you think that?

Comment: I have done the calculations and got the expression given I the question.